# Spring Sock JS connection drops frequently on wildfly 8 server

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, wildfly, sockjs, wildfly-8

I have an application which uses Spring Websocket. It works perfect on Tomcat/WAS -recently we tried to port it on Wildfly. There a sockjs connection is created but as soon as client sends a message the connection drops! I have enabled asyn support for spring dispatcher servlet. Here is the error which I get

```
2014-09-11 23:50:59,459 ERROR [stderr] (default task-40) Exception in thread "default 
task-40" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: UT000029: Channel was closed 
mid chunk, if you have attempted to write chunked data you cannot shutdown the channel 
until after it has all been written.
2014-09-11 23:50:59,462 ERROR [stderr] (default task-40)              at 

io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.responseDone(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:527)

2014-09-11 23:50:59,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-40)              at 
io.undertow.servlet.spec.AsyncContextImpl$3.run(AsyncContextImpl.java:294)

2014-09-11 23:50:59,465 ERROR [stderr] (default task-40)              at 
io.undertow.servlet.spec.AsyncContextImpl$6.run(AsyncContextImpl.java:432)

2014-09-11 23:50:59,466 ERROR [stderr] (default task-40)              at 
io.undertow.servlet.spec.AsyncContextImpl$TaskDispatchRunnable.run(AsyncContextImpl.java:517)

2014-09-11 23:50:59,468 ERROR [stderr] (default task-40)              at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)

2014-09-11 23:50:59,469 ERROR [stderr] (default task-40)              at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)

2014-09-11 23:50:59,471 ERROR [stderr] (default task-40)              at  
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Although it gives error about chunks, there is no explicit multi part data send from client to server and as mentioned above I already have enabled async support for dispatcher servlet of spring which uses it for fallback if WebSocket support is not available

Answer (score 2):

I was using wildfly 8.0 final with With Spring 4.1.0 and JSF 2.0 & JDK 8.0_u25
I was facing same Exception:
  **UT005013: An IOException occurred: java.io.IOException: UT000029: Channel was closed mid chunk, if you  have attempted to write chunked data you cannot shutdown the channel until after it has all been written.**

And my Server CPU Processing increase 25% of each time of exception occurrence.
Alhumdulillah Now I Resolve my problem.

Now I'm using:
Wildfly 8.2.0 Final With Spring 4.1.0 and JSF 2.0 & JDK 8.0_u25

Wildfly 8.2.0 resolve my CPU Processing issue
I observe my server almost 8 days then I realize that when host(Client/User) send some request to server that required some time for calculating/ Server Response time at that user close his browser window or log-out before getting response from server. when Server done his processing and then try to send response to his specific Host/Client request then IO Exception occurs because client closed the browser window.

I Hope this will help you out :)